# How can I use "Google Earth" or "GPS exchange format" files to enhance my SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, local-seo

Google claims that it knows certain [file types](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/indexable-file-types). This includes `Google Earth (.kml, .kmz)` and `GPS eXchange Format (.gpx)` files.

I have some clients who are active regarding locations. For example, a directory of restaurants, or a real-estate website.

What benefits can I get from these file formats for my SEO?

Answer (score 0):

The first question to answer is what other local actions have already been taken for the site and the company to rise in rankings?

It is possible to include Google Earth in the Local SEO strategy. Is it worth the effort? It depends on the market and the competition and, of course, the budget.

Advantages that can result from a Google Earth (stack):

- The visibility in the area increases for several locations.
- The ranking of maps increases for the target region.
- The visibility and position of numerous phrases improves.

Disadvantage:

- Very complex to create (if you want to do it better).
- Required drive stacks (for more efficiency)
- Cost factor !!!
- Can leave footprints

Our opinion and experience: If you are in a highly competitive industry, you can create a .xml and .kml file with all relevant information (description + keywords + zip codes and so on). This file would be uploaded in a Google Stack or simply in the G-Cloud. It does not necessarily have to be made public for everyone, here it is usually enough to publish the link only for people who own the link. Google already indexes the file.

In your case, I would create a simple Google Earth .kml file and put it into a "folder" in Google Drive. I would then promote the link a bit and then, after a few weeks, evaluate and adjust the results.

The whole thing becomes effective if you include it in your link strategy (stacking).
The advice of an SEO backlink professional is certainly appropriate here.

Comment: What does quote can leave footprints " mean?

Comment: -"Can leave footprints"

This means that Google may consider such an action as a violation of its guidelines. That's why you need an SEO expert as well. If you create it as a simple .kml or .xml file and upload it to your G-Drive, it's a normal process and not a problem. But if you work with aggressive link strategies, you leave traces that Google could clearly interpret as manipulation (footprints: user-agents, account, ip, location etc. etc.). It must always be natural and look like it. This is also possible in a normal way.